# Change primaryPalette color of Angular MD dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following module config for my Angular MD theme.

```
.config(['$mdThemingProvider', function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette(color).accentPalette('orange');
}]);
```

I want to be able to change the primaryPalette dynamically using the variable `color` (I want to use a themechanger on my site). However I can't seem to access the config section at runtime, and I also am not able to use the $mdThemingProvider anywhere out of the config section. Any ideas how to solve this?

https://material.angularjs.org/#/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme